# HTTPS data returned not saving

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an object class set up called WebCalls. In this class, I make a web call and return some JSON from an HTTPS server. Now the methods work perfectly, I have tested and the data returns fine. However my problem is, I can't access the data returned outside the class.

The code to retrieve the data is below

Interface

```
@interface WebCall : NSObject{

    NSString *phoneNumber;
    NSString *jsonData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *jsonData;


-(void) getData: (NSString *) link;


@end

Implementation

@implementation WebCall

@synthesize jsonData;
@synthesize responseData;


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [responseData setLength:0];
}   

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.responseData = nil;
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

       NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    jsonData = s;

}

-(void) getData: (NSString *) link{

        jsonData = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}



@end
```

In interface class I have a string called jsonData. I get and set it using property and synthesise. So after I make web call, I assign the data to jsonData, and I should be able to import web call class, use the getInfo method, have the jsonData returned and then access it using

```
WebCall *wc = [[WebCall alloc] init];
[wc getData:url];
NSLog(@"%@", [c jsonData]);
```

However this just prints out null. And yet if I print out the String in the Webcall class after I recieve the data, it prints out fine. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Updated with complete implementation

Also I can't access the string outside the method. I copied the code to another class, and tried assigning the JSON String, then calling it again in the body, and it comes out null again. Seems I can only print it out in that connection method. Then it seems to clear the String

Edit: What I tried

```
[wc setWebCallDidFinish:^(NSString * json, NSString *test){

    NSLog(@"%@", json);


}];
[wc getData:@"12345"];
```

Comment: Please provide the complete implementation of WebCall

Comment: You any idea on why it is doing this. This is really frustrating, and literally have no idea as to why it is doing this

Comment: In the second set of code what is c?

Comment: That should be wc, I just copied it in wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam the reason jsonData is an empty string is because  [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; runs asynchronously which means on a new thread and it doesn't block. this means that when you call [wc getData:url]; and then immediately call  NSLog(@"%@", [wc jsonData]); the http request hasn't completed yet and the - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection delegate function hasn't been called yet in your WebCall.

For a detailed explanation read this [iOs Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Essentially you need to add a notifier to your WebCall so that it can notify the object which spawns it that the request has finished loading.  I would use a block like so.

```
@interface WebCall : NSObject{

    NSString *phoneNumber;
    NSString *jsonData;
    void(^webCallDidFinish)(NSString *jsonData, id otherRandomVar);
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *jsonData;


-(void) getData: (NSString *) link;
-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *, id))wcdf;

@end

Implementation

@implementation WebCall

@synthesize jsonData;
@synthesize responseData;

-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *,id))wcdf{
    webCallDidFinish = [wcdf copy];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

       NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    jsonData = s;
    webCallDidFinish(jsonData, @"any other object");

}
//all of your other code here
```

Then in the calling code the following

```
WebCall *wc = [[WebCall alloc] init];
[wc setWebCallDidFinish:^(NSString * json, id randomSecondVar) {
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
}];
[wc getData:url];
```

What will happen is the block of code you provide to setWebCallDidFinish will be called after jsonData is loaded.  You could also use the Delegate pattern to accomplish this.  Note that while this asynchronous request is loading you should provide some sort of indicator to your user.

Comment: Thanks soo much!! It worked perfectly, wish I had realized this ealrier, spent hours on this trying get it working. Owe you big time!!!!

Comment: Quick question, how would I return more than one variable. The full process is several links that I must go to get authenticated before I can access the json. This part works fine, but there is a second variable I need to return. Can I return more than one variable using the method you showed me?

Comment: Do you mean into the webCallDidFinish block?  If so you can see examples here of how to use blocks http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

Comment: Yes, I would like to return a second variable in that block if that is possible

Comment: @AdamM Along with the link i mentioned above I also edited my example code to include a second variable.

Comment: Actually quick question, no errors appear when I put that code in. However when I am calling the code and call the second paramater, it comes up with message saying incompatible block pointer types. Any reason for that? Updated my question to show what I tried

Comment: In my code the second parameter is of type id  in your code you provided type NSString

Comment: I had swapped the other parameters over to NSString. But nvm, got it working, reason it was not working is that I had 2 different webcall classes set up, and was using the wrong web cal in my test class. Thanks again for your help!!